# Inserting dashes between two odd numbers

Tags: java

folks. In my program I take a user input of numbers of a `String` type and put `dashes` between `two odd numbers`. For example:

```
Input = 99946    Output = 9-9-946
Input = 56730    Output = 567-30
```

But in my code, if I, for example, write `9933444` then the ouput that I'm getting is: `9-9-9-3-3-3-344444`. It correctly separates the odd numbers by dashes but also **adds extra numbers**. What could be causing this bug ?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DashInsert {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the numbers: ");
        String myString = kbd.nextLine();
        char[] numbers = myString.toCharArray();
        String result = "";

        for(int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++)
        {
            int value1 = Character.getNumericValue(numbers[i]);
            int value2 = Character.getNumericValue(numbers[i-1]);


            if(value1 % 2 != 0 && value2 % 2 != 0)
            {
                result += numbers[i-1] + "-" + numbers[i] + "-";
            }
            else 
                result += numbers[i-1] + "" + numbers[i];
        }
        System.out.println(result);

    }

}
```

Comment: Time to use a debugger, isn't it?

Comment: This is not a code debugging service.  I take it that this is some kind of learning exercise.  If so, then one of the things that you should be learning is how to debug your own code.  There are numerous resources to get you started; e.g. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html.  But the most important resource is between your ears.  Try doing it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code can be simplified a bit (as well as solve the "double char" bug):

```
String str = "9933444";
char[] numbers = str.toCharArray();
String result = "";

for(int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++)
{
    int value1 = Character.getNumericValue(numbers[i-1]);
    int value2 = Character.getNumericValue(numbers[i]);
    result += value1;
    if(value1 % 2 != 0 && value2 % 2 != 0) {
        result += "-";
    }
}
result += numbers[numbers.length - 1];
System.out.println(result);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
9-9-3-3444
```

The reason for the "double char" bug is that every loop prints both the items on the places `i-1` and `i`. which means that `i` will be printed again on the next loop (where it will become `i-1`).

---

In case you're using Java 8 - you can use a `Stream` do something that looks more like what you were originally trying to do:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String str = "9933444";
    List<String> lst = Arrays.asList(str.split(""));
    String res = lst.stream().reduce((a,b) -> {
        if (isOdd(a) && isOdd(b)) {
            return a + "-" + b;
        }
        else {
            return a + b;
        }
    }).get();
    System.out.println(res);
}

// grep the last digit from the string and check if it's odd/even
public static boolean isOdd(String x) {
    if (x.length() > 1) {
        if (x.substring(x.length()-1).equals("-")) {
            x = x.substring(x.length()-3, x.length()-2);
        }
        else {
            x = x.substring(x.length() - 1);
        }
    }
    return Integer.parseInt(x) % 2 == 1;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
9-9-3-3444
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a trivial one-line solution:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?<=[13579])(?=[13579])", "-");
```

This works by matching *between* odd numbers and replacing the (zero-width) match with a dash. The regex is a look behind and a look ahead.

It can be done without look arounds by capturing the odd digits and putting them back using a back reference:

```
str = str.replaceAll("([13579])([13579])", "$1-$2");
```

Both solutions achieve the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The bug is caused by the fact that, even though you are looping through your list of numbers one at a time, you write out two numbers with each loop iteration. Logically, this design will always yield repeated numbers.

Either change your loop to iterate by twos, or print a single number in each loop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother concatenating two odd numbers with the "-" in between them, during the evaluation, just add the "-" after the number that you're checking in each iteration.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the numbers: ");
    String myString = kbd.nextLine();
    char[] numbers = myString.toCharArray();
    
    String result = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        int value1 = Character.getNumericValue(numbers[i]);
        int value2 = i + 1 < numbers.length 
                ? Character.getNumericValue(numbers[i + 1]) 
                : 0;

        if(value1 % 2 != 0 && value2 % 2 != 0) {
            result += numbers[i] + "-";
        } else {
            result += numbers[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Results:

> Input: 99946 Output: 9-9-946
>
> Input: 56730 Output: 567-30
>
> Input: 9933444 Output: 9-9-3-3444