# Scanner.nextInt gives InputMismatchException: For input string: "222234411110000"

Tags: java

In my program I need to insert `-` between two `odd numbers` and `*` between `even numbers` and ignore if there is `0`. For example:

```
Input = 99946   Output = 9-9-94*6
Input = 56647304    Output = 56*6*47-304
```

Method `getDigits()` places the digits of the entered `number` into array cells. Method `insertDashesAsteriks()` returns properly concatenated `String`.

But when I run my program with the following example:

> Please enter the numbers so they could be rearranged: 
>   222234411110000

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException: For input string: "222234411110000"
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at DashInsert2.main(DashInsert2.java:9)
```

then I'm getting `InputMismatchException`. Why am I getting the error?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DashInsert2 {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the numbers so they could be rearranged: ");
        int nums = kbd.nextInt();

        int[] numArray = getDigits(nums);
        System.out.println("The array representation of the numbers is \n");
        System.out.println();

        String result = insertDashesAsteriks(numArray);
        System.out.println("The result is " + result);

    }

    public static int[] getDigits(int numbers)
    {
        int length = Integer.toString(numbers).length();
        int[] temp = new int[length];

        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            temp[i] = numbers % 10;
            numbers = numbers / 10;
        }

        return temp;
    }

    public static String insertDashesAsteriks(int[] numArray)
    {
        String temp = "";
        for(int i = 1; i < numArray.length; i++)
        {
            if(numArray[i] % 2 == 0 && numArray[i-1] % 2 ==0)
            {
                temp = numArray[i-1] + "*" + numArray[i] + "*";
            }
            else if(numArray[i] == 0 || numArray[i-1] == 0)
            {
                temp = numArray[i-1] + "" + numArray[i] + "";
            }
            else if(numArray[i] % 2 != 0 && numArray[i-1] % 2 != 0)
            {
                temp = numArray[i-1] + "-" + numArray[i] + "-";
            }
        }

        return temp; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it a duplicate of your own question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30270866/inserting-dashes-between-two-odd-numbers

Comment: @alfasin same code, different problem sadly

Comment: @Luke *sadly* indeed

Answer (score 5):

Maximum value for `int` is <kbd>2,147,483,647</kbd>

You entered: <kbd>222,234,411,110,000</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to treat the number as a string since the number you input is past the biggest possible 32 bit integer.

Try `kbd.next().charAt(0);` to parse it character by character instead.

Answer (score 1):

First off, if you're reading in `int`s, you're limited to their range. That means numbers beyond about +/- two billion are out of the question. For handling larger number, you can move to larger data types (like `long`) or just handle strings, which have far less stringent limitations.

Once you *are* handling strings, there's a far simpler way (in terms of the code you have to write) to do this substitution using regular expressions:

```
public class Test {
    static String morph(String s) {
        String oldS;
        do {
            oldS = s;
            s = s.replaceAll("([13579])([13579])", "$1-$2");
            s = s.replaceAll("([2468])([2468])", "$1*$2");
        } while (! s.equals(oldS));         
        return s;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println(morph("99946"));
        System.out.println(morph("56647304"));
        System.out.println(morph("222234411110000"));
    }
}
```

The `morph` function simply modifies the string with your substitution rules until it ceases to change. The output of the test harness (using the data you supplied) is:

```
9-9-94*6
56*6*47-304
2*2*2*234*41-1-1-10000
```

---

Now it may be that, if this is a classwork assignment, you're limited in the language facilities you can use. But, since you haven't mentioned that, and no coder in their right mind would (usually) choose a *more* difficult path, you should consider the use of the regular expression method. Code that is shorter is almost always less prone to bugs.

If you *don't* want to use regular expressions, you can still make your code relatively short and well structured, with something like:

```
// Helper functions for inserting characters.

static boolean is2468 (char ch) {
    return (ch == '2' || ch == '4' || ch == '6' || ch == '8');
}

static boolean is13579 (char ch) {
    return (ch == '1' || ch == '3' || ch == '5' || ch == '7' || ch == '9');
}

static String morph(String str) {
    // Use efficient string builder for creating morphed string.

    StringBuilder newStr = new StringBuilder();

    // Last/current character, starting with '0' simplifies
    //   start condition.

    char lastCh, ch = '0';

    // Process every character in string.

    for (int idx = 0; idx < str.length(); idx++) {
        // Transfer previous current to last, get current.

        lastCh = ch;
        ch = str.charAt(idx);

        // Put '-' between two odds, '*' between two non-zero evens.

        if (is13579(lastCh) && is13579(ch))
            newStr.append('-');
        else if (is2468(lastCh) && is2468(ch))
            newStr.append('*');

        // Put character there regardless.

        newStr.append(ch);
    }

    // Return string version of string builder.

    return newStr.toString();
}
```